# How to identify signs(Logos) using windows phone 8 camera

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

HI friends...
I am going to develop Windows phone 8 app (Xaml/C#) which can identify signs (Like famous Logos) using camera. It is like capturing QR code using windows phone. As an example through my application I can scan (like QR code) and identify the Logo which appears in somewhere in board or a picture etc... (Think I have database which is filled with logo information (logo pictures an info) and I connected it to windows phone app.)
So my questions are 
What are the image processing SDKs and libraries I can use to develop this app ?
Is there any Blog post which describes those things?
Any sample codes? 

Thank you very much in Advance 

Comment: Stackoverflow, is for asking assistance on specific coding problems. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically point 5, around asking for library recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a library which has proven to work on WP7 so i'm guessing it will work on WP8 aswell.
It main purpose was augmented reality but its a "vision" library which means you can probably do loads of other vision commands (labelblobs, invert colors etc..)

Link to the library: [Here](http://kodierer.blogspot.nl/2011/05/augmented-mango-slartoolkit-for-windows.html)

Samples of its use: [Here](http://kodierer.blogspot.nl/2011/05/augmented-mango-slartoolkit-for-windows.html)